# replace string in remote file using powershell in jenkins groovy

Tags: windows, powershell, groovy, replace, jenkins-pipeline

Below powershell command works fine and replaces a string in file `C:\test1\.env` on remote host `remotehost7`

```
echo y | plink -ssh -l deploydevuser -pw psww -P 22 remotehost7 -t "powershell -Command '(Get-Content -path C:\test1\.env ) -replace \`http://oldstring.com\`,\`https://newstring.com\` | Set-Content -Path C:\test1\.env'"
```

I wish to trigger the same command using Jenkins groovy script. Below is the code:

```
bat '''
\$stringToReplace = "http://oldstring.com"
\$replaceWith = "https://newstring.com"
\$plinkCmd = "plink -ssh -l deploydevuser -pw psww -P 22 remotehost7"
\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg = "C:\\test1\\.env"

echo "****************starting"

echo "echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path \"\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg\") -replace \"\$stringToReplace\",\"\$replaceWith\" | Set-Content -Path \"\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg\"'"

echo "************\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg****starting"

powershell -Command "echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path \"\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg\") -replace \"\$stringToReplace\",\"\$replaceWith\" | Set-Content -Path \"\$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg\"'"
    '''
```

However, i get the below error:

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\ityD_feature_imp_exp_url>echo "****************starting"

"****************starting"



D:\Jenkins\workspace\ityD_feature_imp_exp_url>echo "echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg") -replace "$stringToReplace","$replaceWith" | Set-Content -Path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg"'"

"echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg") -replace "$stringToReplace","$replaceWith" | Set-Content -Path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg"'"



D:\Jenkins\workspace\ityD_feature_imp_exp_url>echo "************$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg****starting"

"************$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg****starting"



D:\Jenkins\workspace\ityD_feature_imp_exp_url>powershell -Command "echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg") -replace "$stringToReplace","$replaceWith" | Set-Content -Path "$updatedRemotePackagePathCyg"'"

At line:1 char:22

+ echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path $updatedRemotePackagePath ...

+                      ~~

Unexpected token '-t' in expression or statement.

At line:1 char:10

+ echo y | ${plinkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path $updatedRemotePackagePath ...

+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

At line:1 char:25

+ ... linkCmd} -t '(Get-Content -path $updatedRemotePackagePathCyg) -replac ...

+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Unexpected token ''(Get-Content -path $updatedRemotePackagePathCyg) -replace $stringToReplace,$replaceWith |

Set-Content -Path $updatedRemotePackagePathCyg'' in expression or statement.

    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: The error messages suggests that `${plinkCmd}` isn't being expanded (replaced by the variable's value).

Comment: i tried changing `| ${plinkCmd} -t ` to -> `| \${plinkCmd} -t ` but getting the same error.

Comment: @mklement0 can u suggest if using `powershell '''`  block instead of `bat '''`  will help and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing batch-file syntax with PowerShell syntax, which cannot work.

- Use batch-file syntax consistently, notably `SET` to define variables, and `%...%` to reference them.
- The `powershell.exe` call as shown in the first snippet in the question wouldn't work, for several reasons, but primarily because enclosing the commands in `'...'` on the command line when PowerShell is called from the *outside* causes them to be treated as *verbatim strings* rather than as commands.

Try the following:

- As in your attempt, `\` are escaped as `\\` for the sake of Groovy.
- Generally, due to using `'''` Groovy string literals, there is *no* need to escape `$` chars. (there are none in the solution below).

```
bat '''\
@echo off

set "stringToReplace=http://oldstring.com"
set "replaceWith=https://newstring.com"
set "updatedRemotePackagePathCyg=C:\\test1\\.env"
set "plinkCmd=plink -ssh -l deploydevuser -pw psww -P 22 remotehost7"

:: Construct the full command line.
:: Note: The assumption is that the variable values do not 
::       contain embedded ' (single quotes).
::       To cmd.exe, what is between \\"...\\" is *unquoted*, hence
::       the need to ^-escape the second | too.
set cmdLine=echo y^| %plinkCmd% -t "powershell -Command \\"(Get-Content '%updatedRemotePackagePathCyg%') -replace '%stringToReplace%', '%replaceWith%' ^| Set-Content '%updatedRemotePackagePathCyg%'\\""

echo "****************starting"

:: Echo the command line. Note the need to escape the "|" chars.
echo %cmdLine:|=^|%

echo "************ %updatedRemotePackagePathCyg% ****starting"

:: Invoke the command line.
%cmdLine%
'''
```